# Grid scrolling issue in EXT.JS 4.0.5, not accounting for toolbar heights

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got this grid:

[image]

Any idea why it would be doing this? I know the inner panel needs to be 350px, and applying this in firebug works fine, but of course Ext likes to recalculate everything on the fly and I can't figure out where to apply a height to the inside panel to get it to show the right behavior.

I'm aware 4.0.5 uses virtual scrollbars, and I've disabled them by setting `scroll: false` on the grid component, and adding `style: { overflowX: 'hidden', overflowY: 'scroll' }` to its viewconfig. The problem is that the inside panel isn't accounting for the toolbar heights, and its pushing the scrollbar under its container. I can't upgrade extjs, either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug that was addressed in 4.1, however I can't really test your code so it's hard to tell, you can try doing this in the grid's `viewready` event:

```
grid.determineScrollbars();
```

As covered [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-determineScrollbars) in the 4.07 docs.

**Edit:**

How about simply trying to relayout the component after the `viewready` event:

```
grid.on('viewready', function(grid) {
    grid.doComponentLayout()
});
```

(Or the MVC way for event handling if you're using that)

Comment: Aye, they took out these damned virtual scrollbars and went with the browsers native scrolling. But due to dependencies on other aspects of the library, I can't upgrade to the newer version. Its frustrating because these scrolling issues keep coming up and its a different solution each time. determinescrollbars() doesn't work :(

Comment: @Gallen added another thought above

Comment: No luck there either. I appreciate your help, though :)

Comment: I ripped the application apart, removed the fit layout and grid scrolling altogether and let the panel scroll instead, now the grid is as long as it needs to be. Over the weekend I'll be looking into upgrading to 4.1 to prevent these issues from happening in the future.

I gave you the answer because those methods have helped in the past for very similar issues.